# Microsoft Chart Controls in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net-4.0

Is this possible? I installed them, but they don't appear. Do I have to import them or something?

Comment: You just have to add the Reference, but... If Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (14.0.0, I think) is on the references you can have some conflitcs. It happened to me after importing from VS2008 to VS2010

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please, take a look: [How use MS chart control with VS 2010?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vbgeneral/thread/3168ddbb-4b4f-445f-89a2-b453f30701ba/)

> I haven't tried it with VS2010, but I would assume the process for using it is exactly the same as described there for other versions of VS.  It won't appear in the tool box until you instal the add-ons

Answer (score 6):

If you cannot see the Chart control in the Toolbox, right click in the Toolbox, select Choose Items, and then select the following namespaces in the .NET Framekwork Components tab:

System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting

System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Comment: Yes if you already have 3.5 Chart controls installed then this method works amazingly!

Answer (score 1):

According to this [blog post](http://dotnetfacts.blogspot.com/2009/01/free-microsoft-chart-control-for-net-35.html) from January 2010:

> The Microsoft Chart Control is available as separate installation for .NET Framework 3.5 and will be included in .NET Framework 4.0.

It could be that the controls haven't been updated to work with VS2010 because of this. If they're not in the Beta 2 by default (I don't have it installed on this machine to check) then it might be that they're only going to be included in the full release.

Answer (score 1):

The Chart controls are included in version 4. Here's where you can find the types:

- ASP.NET:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.aspx
- Winforms:
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd489065%28v=VS.100%29.aspx