# Dynamic Graph Creation using c# and VS 2010

Tags: c#, html, visual-studio-2010

My website needs to generate dynamic graphs. Im writting it in c# using Visual Studio 2010. I have searched the MSDN site and have found the asp:chart tag. The problem is It only seems to have a VS 2008 installer which dosnt work on VS 2010. Does anyone know a way of setting this up and running in VS 2010 or suggest a reliable graph tool?e

I have installed [The Chart library](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422)
but have been unabel to install the VS add on because its for 2008

[Add On](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23903)

and I have been unable to find a 2010 link?

Also I getting data visulisation underlined in red on:

`using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;`

Comment: how it is related asp:chat tag and graph? do you mean asp:chart tag and you need charts? if so http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14422

Comment: Thanks for the responce. Thats the first thing I did but VS 2010 isnt recognising the tag?

Comment: because it is not defined in web.config, check this article: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/072209-1.aspx

Comment: regarding addon - i think it was answered before: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2043589/212121

Comment: Im still not having any luck. I have re-installed the .exe from the link you provided and it still is saying <asp:Chart is not recognized. Acording the the site you provided the config file should be updated automaticly. I shouldent have to make any changes. Thank for you help though.